# How to handle improper editing/rollbacks by questioner

Tags: discussion, edits, behavior

I have just started editing questions, and I found a weird case in my first attempt. The asker has made various attempts to [discard edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35574727/revisions) to his question that have been made by various Stack Overflow community members. Moreover, the edits that he is making don't comply with site standards. However, his question may have a place here with the proper edits.

So, my question is to how to deal with users who discard edits made by experienced community members. I don't want to flag the question, but I do want to let the user know that these edits were made to his question for his benefit.

*Edit:*
Got another [example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92457/build-connection-string-in-dashboard-designer-performancepoint-service) where user is complaining about [edits](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/92457/revisions) made by Stackoverflow community member.

Comment: This doesn't look like he's doing this on purpose. More like that he doesn't refresh his page before starting to edit, so he doesn't see the newest edit to his question and practically reverts them.

Comment: I would think in my ignorant state (see my comment below :) that some links to site policy would be a nice way to gently [prod the OP in the base question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574727/retrieve-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp-form) toward the light.

Comment: Are you sure he's intentionally editing in the wrong things, or is it possible he is taking a long time to complete an edit and you are much faster than he is?

Comment: I would recommend replacing "immature" with "incorrect" in your title.  The way it is now comes off a little insulting.  We want to be able to refer the user to this post so they can understand the concerns raised.

Comment: @Trisped: I remember when *my* maturity was called into question on Stack Overflow... man those were fun times.

Comment: I find the editing of my questions and answers to be an extremely annoying part of using this site. I like things I write to be in my own voice, but people here have a very strong idea of what is an objectively "correct" way of saying something. I usually roll back edits that just change that just make minor changes without adding any real value for this reason. Maybe this user doesn't think your edits are "for his benefit," as you say.

Comment: @Drew C: Grammar can arguably be subjective, but formatting is completely objective. You don't put text that isn't code ("prose") in a code block, period. That said, edits that significantly rewrite a post in the editor's own style tend to rub me the wrong way regardless of how broken the original post was and of the editor's intentions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

At a certain point I don't think there's anything you can do. You could try leaving a comment pointing out you're trying to help but if the OP continues rolling back or changing your edits your best bet is probably just to leave it and move on.

Of course, if the edits amount to vandalism then a moderator flag is appropriate.

Comment: Comments would work best.  It is VERY hard for a new user to navigate this site.  Since there is no peer-to-peer communication offered, a new user could merely feel attacked and feel as if their post was being vandalized.

Comment: The point of my comment is that I just don't see how this is an issue of confusion over the rules. It is plain to anyone who bothers to look that each of the edits were a significant improvement over the original, and that the subsequent edits by the author undid those improvements. This isn't a case where someone edited out a "thank you" and a new user didn't understand our policies on that. This is a case where incorrect formatting made the question literally *unreadable*, and it was fixed by an edit. No one, even new users, want their question to be unreadable.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe they started editing before the other edit happened, got some warning or other and said "I don't know what that means, I just want my edit in there", and committed, overwriting the old edit.  That isn't "irredeemably stupid", that is "I just want to edit my question, not understand how to do multi-person editing".

Comment: FWIW, I saw a new user yesterday twice revert edits that put his code into a code block. So after rolling it back I left a polite comment explaining that people were trying to improve his question. Today he replied with a nice apology, saying he's new and just got confused.

Comment: @CodyGray Normally I would agree with you. Given, however, that revision 4 was the user fixing an edit he undid, the evidence is more in favor of editing conflicts and the user not fully understanding the system in this case.

Answer (score 13):

Upon the first few edits to their posts, new users should get additional information on what this is all about.

> Hello there,
>
> an edit was made to your question/answer by some other user.
>   We encourage users to edit other users content. With enough reputation, you too will be able to edit posts of others.
>
> This is a little bit different from the rest of the internet.
>
> For now take a look at the edit. Do you like what you see? If the edit helps you, approve it, if not reject it.
>
> ```
>             -------------------            -------------------
>             | I like the edit |            | I hate the edit |
>             -------------------            -------------------
> ```

Getting a badge for scrolling to the bottom of the tour page does not necessarily mean users understand all the consequences and "every day"-things on this site. Giving a few hints here and there shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Well, just one thing: Even if the OP hates the edit, it can still be a useful edit which should be approved. Some are adamantly opposed to any edit to their own personal post, especially if it removes fluff and focuses it.

Comment: @Deduplicator when clicking on "I hate the edit", a text unrolls that explains why and how some edits are good and should be approved.

Comment: @null, yes and that also gives an option to say accept/deny, but the deny button links to a are you sure yes/no popup, which may or may not link to an edit requiring the user to type `I know what I'm doing and accept the consequences of my actions`.

Comment: Just use jQuery to move the "I hate the edit" box around so that it becomes unclickable. All problems solved.

Comment: @Cody Gray: http://www.pagetutor.com/idiot/idiot.html (Java applet, made in the old days, actually easily winnable)

Answer (score 11):

If the user doesn't want your help you'll eventually have to accept that and move on. Leave a comment explaining why you changed what you did and then, if the question is of poor quality, vote it down/closed and hope that the user can learn from their mistakes.